# nCipher HSM retarget JCE key

Tags: jce, pkcs#11, hsm

Is it possible to "retarget" keys generated via the ncipher JCE API to pkcs11? I know that you can retarget via the generatekey command but I don't see how to do it to an existing JCE key. The first prompt is for the "source application" and the [options don't seem to include JCE](https://docops.ca.com/ca-apm/9-6/en/administrating/apm-security/using-ncipher-with-ca-cem/working-with-ncipher-keys-and-operator-cards#WorkingwithnCipherkeysandoperatorcards-Retargetingthewebserverprivatekey). Does it support other options beyond the ones listed there or should I be looking at a different way of retargeting?

The ultimate goal here is to export a couple keys (asymmetric and symmetric) that were generated via nCipher's JCE API (yes, I know that an HSM's job is to secure the keys and exporting is usually not a good idea but it is a requirement here). We are able to export keys that were generated via the PKCS11 interface but not ones that were generated via the JCE so our thinking is that if we can retarget it from JCE to PKCS11 we might be able to export these keys as well. If there is another way to do this we are open to that as well.

Lastly, the JCE keys show up as "recovery enabled" when executing the nfkminfo on them. Does that mean that they are exportable or does recovery here mean something else?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Disclaimer: I work for Thales e-Security but do not speak for the company.

Yes you can retarget a jcecsp key to pkcs11.  If you have any jcecsp keys in your kmdata/local, /opt/nfast/bin/generatekey will offer jcecsp as a source option.  If you have no keys of that ilk, it will quietly omit that option from the source list.  **However,** this retarget process may not do what you think it does.  All retargeting does is change the application type and potentially the associated metadata: it doesn't change the fundamental capabilities of the key as those were baked into the protected key blob at generation time and cannot be changed.

The Security World uses nShield key ACLs to limit the key's capabilities (Sign, Verify, Encrypt, Decrypt, Wrap, Be Wrapped, etc.).  PKCS#11 pulls its parameters (CKA_SIGN, etc.) directly from the key ACLs, and when generating keys through the API, the ACLs saved in the key blob are derived directly from the parameters in the key template.  If you set CKA_SENSITIVE to FALSE, and your Security World allows it, you can generate and save an exportable key. JCE is not that sophisticated: it has no concept of key capabilities at all, so the Provider has to guess at the user's intent with the key and it defaults to a fairly generous set.  However, since as you point out the whole idea of HSMs is to protect key bits and not let you have them, Export is not one of the defaults.  And what's not baked into the key file when you create it, you don't get by retargeting the key.

One thing you could do if you want to use JCE is to generate the key using a different Provider and then store it in an *nCipher.sworld* KeyStore using the nCipherKM Provider: this will import the key into the Security World (if your World allows that) and save it as a key_jcecsp_* file.  However this has nothing to do with key security so from an HSM perspective it's not recommended. Another thing you could do is to drop down to the native nCore API, generate the key with the ACL entries you require, and then polymorph it to a JCE Key Object and save it in the HSM-backed KeyStore.  You can shoot yourself in the foot as many times as you want with the ACLs on the key you create.  The polymorphing is very poorly documented: ask Thales Support and they can guide you.

Finally, the Recovery capability means that in addition to the Working Key blob which may be protected by an Operator Card Set, the key file has a Recovery Blob.  This is in case that Operator Card Set is lost: the Recovery Blob can be opened up by the Administrator Card Set of the Security World using the rocs utility (Replace Operator Card Set), which will write a new key file under a new OCS.  No, this does not mean the key is exportable.  It just means that you are protected against losing the OCS.  Of course losing the ACS is a non-starter as that is your Root of Trust.